# How to Sort ip addresses and merge two files in efficent manner using perl or *nix commands?

Tags: perl, unix, sorting, merge

(*) This problem should be done in perl or any *nix commands.

i'm working on a program and efficiency matters.The file1 consists ip addresses and some other data:

```
index ipsrc     portsrc  ip dest     port src
8 128.3.45.10 2122 169.182.111.161 80 (same ip src and dst)
9 128.3.45.10 2123 169.182.111.161 22 (same ip src and dst)
10 128.3.45.10 2124 169.182.111.161 80 (same ip src and dst)
19 128.3.45.128 62256 207.245.43.126 80
```

and other file2 looks like (file1 and file2 are in different order)

```
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186
128.3.44.112 pay-per-view 148.184.171.6 netbios-ssn 0 0 3 186 3 186
128.3.45.12 cadabra-lm 148.184.171.6 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186
```

1- SORT file1 using IP address in second column and SORT file2 using IP address in first column

2- Merge the 1st, 3rd and 5th columns of File1 with File 2

i need to create a new file which will look:

```
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> 2122 80 8
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> 2123 22 9
128.3.44.112 pay-per-view 148.184.171.6 netbios-ssn 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> * * *
128.3.45.12 cadabra-lm 148.184.171.6 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> * * *
```

basically port numbers and index number will be added.

Comment: Are you interested in memory efficiency, or CPU/time efficiency?

Comment: What's the format of the 2nd file?  It seems like the first 2 lines repeat the same source and dest IPs, but with different hostnames.  That seems like a mistake?  If not, it's going to make it much harder (impossible?) to uniquely map back to the first file.

Comment: @jimtut, file2 has the same ip addresses but only port numbers are decoded. For that reason, i think that sorting both files using the src ip addresses will give the row by row match, then i can merge it and create the output file.

Comment: You can sort the first file doing something like this:    cat file1 | awk '{ print $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $1 }' | sort > file 1a

Comment: But, I may be missing something, because I can't see any way to uniquely tie some of the 2nd file's rows (like "128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm...") to any of the 1st file's rows.  Since the IP address occurs multiple times in each file, what's to stop "128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm" to getting matched to the 2nd row in the 1st file (port 2123, instead of port 2122)?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question several hours ago?

Comment: @DVK, thanks for the perl code. After your answer, i realized that matching will be problem for that reason i tried to modify the question, but instead asked a new using sort and merge it has better look and easier.

Comment: @jimtut, yes uniquely tie two files is problem, @DVK made me clear. so that's why i'm trying to sort both files and then merge it, by sorting it will match row by row. then we can merge the columns as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DVK: Yes, I did ask the same question, once before I tried writing some code, and then again after trying some code, and getting stumped by how to uniquely identify/merge lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superficially, it seems an obvious application for `sort` and `join`:

```
sort -k2 file1 > sorted.1
sort -k1 file2 > sorted.2
join -1 2 -2 1 -a 2 -e '*' \
    -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.10,1.1,1.3,1.5 \
    sorted.1 sorted.2
```

However, the output from that is:

```
128.3.44.112 pay-per-view 148.184.171.6 netbios-ssn 0 0 3 186 3 186 * * *
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186 8 2122 80
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 8 2122 80
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186 9 2123 22
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 9 2123 22
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186 10 2124 80
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 10 2124 80
128.3.45.12 cadabra-lm 148.184.171.6 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 * * *
```

Close, but no dice: the problem is that the IP address 128.3.45.10 appears thrice in file1 and twice in file2 and `join` therefore creates 6 rows (a Cartesian product).

---

This appears to be an application that needs to consume/destroy entries as they are used.  This suggests we are going to need to use Perl (or a similar scripting language).  It is then not clear that we need to sort file1; we need to read file1 and create a structure with a hash keyed on IP address (field 2) where the key points to an array of strings, each record containing just the three fields (1, 3, 5) that are needed.

Then we process file2 in sequence, finding the matching IP address in the hash, and using the first entry in the array - or stars if there is no such entry.  We can add the '`-->`' requested in the question too.

This leads to the fairly simple program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %file1 = read_file1("file1");

sub read_file1
{
    my($file) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open $file for reading ($!)";
    my %file1;
    while (my $line = <$fh>)
    {
        my @fields = split / /, $line;
        my $ip = $fields[1];
        $file1{$ip} = [ ] unless defined $file1{$ip};
        push @{$file1{$ip}}, "$fields[0] $fields[2] $fields[4]";
    }
    return %file1;
}

my $file2 = "file2";
open my $f2, '<', $file2 or die "Failed to open $file2 for reading ($!)";

while (my $line = <$f2>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my($ip) = ($line =~ m/^(\S+) /);
    my $aux = "* * *";
    if (defined $file1{$ip})
    {
        $aux = shift @{$file1{$ip}};
        delete $file1{$ip} if scalar @{$file1{$ip}} == 0;
    }
    print "$line --> $aux\n";
}
```

And the output is this - exactly as requested:

```
128.3.45.10 ioc-sea-lm 169.182.111.161 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186  --> 8 2122 80
128.3.45.10 hypercube-lm 169.182.111.161 https 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> 9 2123 22
128.3.44.112 pay-per-view 148.184.171.6 netbios-ssn 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> * * *
128.3.45.12 cadabra-lm 148.184.171.6 microsoft-ds 0 0 3 186 3 186 --> * * *
```

There is nary a sort in sight - so it is reasonably efficient.

Comment: Since the dotted IP address representation is a representation of a 32-bit value, it's possible to do numeric sort on IPs, transformint them into 32bit: ip32=ip1*256*256*256+ip2*256*256+ip3*256+ip4. Then it's possible to transform a 32bit value back to dot-IP. This will allow the correct sort on IP addresses (128.3.45.12 will go after 128.3.45.10, not after 128.3.45.112).

Comment: thanks for sharing your time. The ip addresses can be sorted as: sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4

Comment: @mbaitoff, @berkay: yes, there are a number of ways of sorting the output if that is required.  The requested output in the question is sorted - alphanumerically; it is also the order of the input data.